# Import Objective-C vendored framework from parent pod using Swift (for a mixed project)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a podspec setup as follows:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "TMGAdvertising"
  spec.default_subspecs = ["Core"]
  *** [extra stuff removed] ***

  spec.subspec 'Core' do |tmgadvertising|
    *** [extra stuff removed] ***
  end

  spec.subspec 'Inneractive' do |inneractive|
    inneractive.dependency "TMGAdvertising/Core"
    inneractive.private_header_files  = "TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/SDK/*.h", "TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/Adapters/*.h"
    inneractive.public_header_files  = "TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/InneractiveWrapper.h"
    inneractive.source_files  = ["TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/Adapters/*.{h,m,swift}", "TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/SDK/*.{h,m,swift}", "TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/InneractiveWrapper.{h,m,swift}"]
    inneractive.vendored_frameworks = "TMGAdvertising/AdNetworkSupport/Inneractive/SDK/*.framework"
    inneractive.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => ['-ObjC'] }
  end
end
```

I have no problem writing wrapper classes for the Inneractive framework in Obj-C (housed within TMGAdvertising). Here's one of my example Obj-C wrappers:

```
#import "InneractiveWrapper.h"
@import IASDKCore;

@implementation InneractiveWrapper

+ (void)initializeSDK:(NSString *)appId {
    [[IASDKCore sharedInstance] initWithAppID:appId];    
}

@end
```

The problem is that I don't want to be writing my wrappers in Objective-C -- I'd prefer to write them in Swift.

Normally I could use a bridging header to accomplish this (that's how it was setup before when integrated directly into the app) but since this is a subspec my understanding is that's not possible.

My question is: **is there any way I can directly import this vendored Inneractive framework in a Swift file located in the TMGAdvertising pod?**

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you should be able to import the file in your Bridging Header.

```
@import IASDKCore;
```